# How can I disable stats in some sections when it is enabled by default?

Tags: haproxy

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not entirely sure this question is more appropriate in some other exchange site (maybe for sysadmins?)

Straight forward. If `stats` is enabled in default, how can I disable it in a frontend or backend? (`stats disable` throws an unknown parameter error)

```
defaults
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm "Haproxy Statistics"
    stats auth user:password
```

Answer (score 0):

About `stats scope`, from the manual...

> When this statement is specified, only the sections enumerated with this
>   statement will appear in the report. All other ones will be hidden. This
>   statement may appear as many times as needed if multiple sections need to be
>   reported. Please note that the name checking is performed as simple string
>   comparisons, and that it is never checked that a give section name really
>   exists.

[Configuration Manual version 1.8.19](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-stats%20scope)

So anyone should be able to set

```
stats scope frontend-name1
stats scope frontend-name2
stats scope backend-name1
```

You are still out of luck if all you wanted was to go to your section and simply type

`stats disable`